# Making a request to google by javaScript

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've the following code in Java Script:

```
var requestData =
                {
                    "homeMobileCountryCode": 732,
                    "homeMobileNetworkCode": 123,
                    "radioType": "gsm",
                    "carrier": "Vodafone",
                    "cellTowers":
                    [
                        {
                            "cellId": 21282,
                            "locationAreaCode": 2110,
                            "mobileCountryCode": 732,
                            "mobileNetworkCode": 123,
                            "age": 0,
                            "signalStrength": (57 - 110)
                        }
                    ]
                }
var encoded = $.toJSON(requestData);
$.ajax({
                url: "https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyA8UJK3m8_X_6GV3T5EWHc86GIuMhITu34",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: encoded,
                success: function (response) {
                    var location = response.location;
                    var lat = location.latitude;
                    var lon = location.longitude;
                    var address = location.address.street_number + " " + location.address.street + " " + location.address.city + " " + location.address.county + " " + location.address.country;
                                },
                error: function (er) {
                    alert("error " + er.message + " codigo: " + er.code);
                }
            });
```

The request doesn't return me nothing and on alert error: apears object undefined, so, have any of you an example of invocation to this service to google using JSON ?? I'm working on ASP.Net
[image]

---

Hi i don't have experience making this kind of request, I have the follow code:

```
Tower tower = new Tower();

        tower.MobileCountryCode = "310";
        tower.MobileNetworkCode = "260";
        tower.CellsTowers = new List<CellTower>();
        tower.CellsTowers.Add(new CellTower()
        {
            CellId = "39627456",
            LocationAreaCode = "40495",
            MobileCountryCode = "310",
            MobileNetworkCode = "260",
            SignalStrength = "-95",
            Age = "0"
        });

        string jsonFormat = ToJSON(tower);

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=AIzaSyA8UJK3m8_X_6GV3T5EWHc86GIuMhITu34" + jsonFormat);
```

And I have thw follow function:

```
string ToJSON(object obj)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
```

But the service response with: Error 400, invalid request ...

Any idea ??

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) from JavaScript. This is a JSON API. It is meant for use only from your server, not from JavaScript code.

The API returns a JSON result, and that is something you can't do with a cross-domain request from JavaScript unless the API allows it via CORS or provides a JSONP response. Unless I'm mistaken, this API does neither of those, so you can't use it from JavaScript.

If you want to do geocoding from JavaScript, you can use the [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) in the Maps API. I don't think this supports the radio tower stuff you're using though - at least the documentation doesn't mention it.

Also, you posted your API key in your question. If this was a browser API key, that's no problem, but if it was a server API key of the sort you would normally use with the Geolocation API, that key is now compromised. Go to your [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), delete this key, and create a new one - and don't share that new key!

Comment: Yes. It doesn't matter what language you use, but it has to be server code, not browser code.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
        var jsonFormat = JSON.stringify(rpcReq);

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Also look at the API documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/?hl=zh-CN

and disregard the above statements about "server only".

(The comments about the API key are generally valid.)